# how to read web services with .Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-services, client

Hi all I need to be able to make a client using .Net which will be able to read web services from the internet.

I don't understand the approach. As for example I need to be able to read this kind of document [LINK](http://developer.ebay.com/webservices/Finding/latest/FindingService.wsdl) Can someone provide me with a example or a link of how to achieve this?

Comment: Here is a good explanation for both creating and using web service http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8257/How-to-make-a-simple-WebService-and-consume-it

Comment: @aliassce I saw that... This is really a simple example and I need to understand it on a higher lvl to achieve this

Comment: No matter how complex the object transferred  you don't have to deal with returning xml file. It is just an object with properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Visual Studio, create a new project - or use an existing one. In the solution tree, right click and "Add new web reference", enter the Url for the WSDL - the link you posted. Visual Studio will create a namespace and classes based on the WSDL (Web Service Description Language) that you can use to create an instance of your web service and methods.

Cheers
Simon

Comment: I was thinking of making a program that you can write url and then It can read from a WSDL

Comment: so you want to create the web service classes on the fly? So the classes are not hardcoded in at compile time? Is that it?

Comment: yes that's it...I need to be able to ready any wsdl when you type url

Comment: not sure what you describe is practical or possible. You might want to have a look at this http://blogs.msdn.com/b/saveenr/archive/2009/08/11/a-walkthrough-of-dynamically-compiling-c-code.aspx

Comment: I think that your approach will work for me I just need show wsdl file formated. I need to make asp. Net project

Comment: If you just need to read the WSDL description and display it, that's much easier. As Dour High Arch says below - read the file with HTTP Request if you just want to show it. If you want to use the service, do as I suggest. Please put more effort into describing your problem and what you want - as said below - your question is poorly defined.

Comment: can you give me an example please

Comment: You haven't said what you want

Comment: I need a simple WSDL reader in c# with that HTTP Request that you have said. Can you show me how to read it easily?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is poorly-defined. What does "make a client" mean? You want to see the WSDL? Type its URL in a web browser. You want to read it programmatically? Read it via HTTP; it's just an XML document. You want to use a specific web service? You have to contact the provider; each web service can be totally different.

Do you want to contact every possible web service by parsing the WSDL, not by asking the provider? You have set yourself an extremely difficult task. Why do you want to do that? What are you trying to achieve? Please tell us exactly what you are trying to do, and show us [what you have tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com/).